# Vue, Firebase, Vuexfire: How to keep track of the current user?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex, vuexfire

I am building an app with vue and vuex and connect it to Firebase like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/firestore";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

I then import `auth` and use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `signOut` to sign up, sign in and sign out users.

What I want to do now is keeping track of who is logged in and display their e-mail address (for example). I learnt that I can use `onAuthStateChanged` like

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   console.log(user);
});
```

But where do I put this? And how can I make the `user` variable available in the whole app?

I though of saving it to vuex, but I have never seen this and began to doubt that this is a good way. What is more, my mutations seem to be blocked by `mutations: vuexfireMutations` so that I could not save the `user` to the store even if I wanted to.

Thanks for any hints!

---

Edit:
Found out that adding own mutations to `vuexfireMutations` works like this:

```
  setUser(state, payload) {
    state.user = payload;
  },
  setError(state, payload) {
    state.error = payload;
  },
  ...vuexfireMutations,
```

Comment: Are you using ssr or spa?

Comment: Single page application (I think)

Comment: Vuex is the way to go to save the current user https://levelup.gitconnected.com/firebase-auth-management-in-vue-js-with-vuex-9c4a5d9cedc

Comment: Looks good, thanks! I struggled a while to add my mutations to the vuexfireMutations. I added an answer to my question.